# Steam Login Lightopenid

Tags: php, steam

I have created a index.php for my login with steam for user to use there steam login for my site to get information like their name, avatar, and steam id the problem i'm having is that the data isn't sending to my database I have made a db.php file with all the right details just it's not storing in my database.

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
$db = mysql_select_db("mydbname");



echo "
                <br/>SmallAvatar: <img src='$player->avatar'/>
                <br/>Player ID: $player->steamid
                <br/>Player Name: $player->personaname
                <br/>Profile URL: $player->profileurl 
                ";
            $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE steamid = '$player->steamid'";
            $query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);

            $_SESSION['name'] = $player->personaname;
            $_SESSION['steamid'] = $player->steamid;
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = $player->avatar;

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query_id) == 0) {
                $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO users_steam (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES  ('$player->personaname', '$player->steamid', '$player->avatar')";
                mysqli_query($db, $sql_steam);
            }
```

Comment: put some of your working codes?

Comment: sorry was trying to work out why it wouldn't let me put my code in, I had to delete the normal stuff you put in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require 'openid.php';

include_once("db.php");

$_STEAMAPI = "";

try {
    $openid = new LightOpenID('www.audiochat.xyz/index.php');
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid/?l=english';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        } else {
            echo "<h2>Connect to Steam</h2>";
            echo "<form action='?login' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='image' src='http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_small.png'>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        if($openid->validate()) {
            $id = $openid->identity;
            $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
            preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

            $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$_STEAMAPI&steamids=$matches[1]";
            $json_object= file_get_contents($url);
            $json_decoded = json_decodemysql_select_db($json_object);

        foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
        {
                $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE steamid = $player->steamid";
                $query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_id) == 0) {
                    $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO users_steam (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES  ('$player->personaname', '$player->steamid', '$player->avatar')";
                    mysqli_query($db, $sql_steam);
                }
            }
        } else {
                        echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for that, it's shows the information on the website, but still doesn't store the data in my database if I even need to.

Comment: check out the second link

Comment: Thanks for trying man, it's not the problem I have everything in my code is correct well it looks that way.

Comment: I have updated the code could you give it a look over and see anything worng with it?

Comment: Thanks trying man, it's still having the problem of saving I have no idea what the problem is the video is only 3 months old what I watch and the code works for him.

Comment: Yeah that's the script I have now, doesn't seem to work maybe steam has update their site with this login code. I've had added

Comment: did you try that, because you had some mistakes in the previous script

Comment: Yeah I tried it, but it the same one I have now. besides the 3 lines of code that I added both don't store the data I getting really frustrated that this hasn't worked for about a week.